# Djstripe: ensuring new subscription payment succeeds before confirming successful subscription to customer

Tags: django, stripe-payments

We use `Djstripe` to create Stripe subscriptions on our Django site like so:

```
# Create the Stripe subscription
stripe_subscription = stripe.Subscription.create(
    customer=customer_id,
    items=[{'price': plan_id}],
    expand=['latest_invoice.payment_intent'],
    metadata=metadata,
)

# Sync subscription from Stripe
subscription = Subscription.sync_from_stripe_data(stripe_subscription)
```

The process on Stripe's end seems to be something like:

1. Create the subscription (return status 200)
2. Create the payment intent object that will charge the customer for the subscription
3. Attempt to charge the customer
4. If the charge fails, put the subscription to status "incomplete"

Naively, when we get 200 back from step (1), we proceed as if the payment went through ok, but sometimes it doesn't (step (4) happens).

What is a good way to confirm a successful subscription creation to the customer oly if the subsequent charge succeeds?

Comment: If this is happening when the customer is off-session, you can use webhooks to get notified whether or not charging the customer succeeded or failed and take action to notify the customer after that: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/webhooks

Comment: @codename_duchess This is all on-session. I want to make sure the customer receives a successful subscription message only when the subscription payment succeeds, not merely when the Stripe subscription is created (which happens before the payment is charged).

Comment: I recommend following the flow here then: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/build-subscriptions?ui=elements. It has error handling.